# Return part of text in MS Word field

Tags: ms-word, fieldcodes

I'm just starting to learn MS Word Fields but can't see any solution for my current problem;

I have a field which I want to show ONLY the 9 characters to the left of ".docx" in the file name.
Inserting the file name is of course easy, but cutting it down to just that part is much more difficult.

two questions; 1) is this possible? and 2) how?

Comment: The general answer is No, because the the field language doesn't have functions equivalent to Left(), Mid() and Right(). However, if you are in a position to design and enforce a particular file naming scheme you might be able to do it for those filenames only. What do you mean by "the 9 characters *to the right* of ".docx"

Comment: @slightly snarky Sorry, I meant to the left of...!! Can you expand on the other thing you mentioned? (As it happens I am in a position to design and enforce a file naming scheme)

Comment: Suppose  your file names Are all formatted like this “sometext ninechars.docx” so that you have one “word” (according to Word), a space, another nine-letter Word, then .docx. Then if you use { filename \*Mergeformat } to insert the name, initially you get the filename. Select “some text” and mark the text as hidden, then the same for .docx. Then save the document under another name with that structure and update the field. It’s fragile though. Word basically splits the name into “words” and reapplies the formatting you applied to each “word“.

Comment: There is another way that can be made to work on Windows but which relies on an external file and a naming convention.

Comment: @slightlysnarky That actually seems like a great idea - i'll try that on monday and let you know if it works. MMTs!!!

Comment: BTW you will need `\*Mergeformat`, not just *Mergeformat.

Comment: @slightlysnarky Sorry not to get back to you. I tried it but couldn't figure out what you meant when you said 'mark the text as hidden' ... and about the same time I thought up a workaround that involved adding a macro into the master doc that triggered the first time the doc is opened if certain conditions are met (to make sure it didn't affect the master ones) ... haven't finished that yet though. MTs anyway.

Comment: Out of curiosity though, what did you mean by 'mark as hidden' ?

Comment: I meant “select the text you want hide then go into the Font dialog and check the Hidden box”. But since you can do it, a macro-based solution is undoubtedly better anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. No.
2. N/A